# c# calling async function from constructor gives green underline in VS

Tags: c#

say I am doing something async and calling this function from the class constructor:

```
public partial class Page_MainMenuDetail : TabbedPage
{
    ObservableCollection<AdsType> mainList = new ObservableCollection<AdsType>();
    public Page_MainMenuDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadMainContent(false);
    }

    private async Task LoadMainContent(bool loadMore)
    {
        if (!loadMore)
        {
            mainList = await ReloadAdapter.LoadAllAds(0, 4);
            listview_mainView.ItemsSource = mainList;
        }
    }
}
```

My reloadAdapter is just a class that makes an API call and returns an observable collection. But since I await for the reload adapter result, the `LoadMainFunction()` function has to be async. But that means, that when I call it from inside the constructor it looks like this in the framework (VS):

[image]

The green line indicates that the function is not beeing awaited. Which is true, but I cannot await inside a constructor (as you cannot make a constructor async).

Is this my wrongdoing or is this a common thing?
Ofc I can put the `LoadMainContent()` into another function that itself is async nbut not a task, and then call that from the constructor, but that is just a workaround to get rid of the green underline.

Or maybe I am doing this concept wrong?

Comment: What would happen if you tried to use `mainList` before `LoadMainContent` has completed? That's what the warning is telling you.

Comment: Overall, it's a bad practice to do any I/O calls from the constructor thus async ctors most likely won't ever be supported. Rethink your implementation, maybe introduce the `Init()` method instead and call it after object instantiation, also add protection mechanism like `bool isInitialized`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, C# / .NET does not currently support async constructors, so you'd have to use either an async static factory method, or an async initialize method *after* the constructor has finished; however - this line is not true:

> that is just a workaround to get rid of the green underline.

This is *not* just a workaround; if you haven't awaited an async method, then *you don't know when it has finished*, so you can't rely on the state that it is meant to initialize - and you have have inadvertent thread-safety issues (as you now *effectively* have two active executions, which is comparable to two active threads). As such, refactoring (in one of the ways cited above) is necessary for correctness.

Comment: In the specific case of an MVVM GUI app, I recommend [this kind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding) of refactoring.